# How to add custom header for new datatables with jquery-ui integration?

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables, datatables-1.10

I want to migrate DataTable initialization to newest version. But I didn't find any possibilities to implement custom header in declarative way. dataTables.jqueryui.js is included.
Obsolete way:
`DataTable {
    bJqueryUI: true,
    sDom: '<"H"<"#custom-id">f>t'
}`
I could repeat this behaviour only with this spike:
`DataTable {
    dom: '<"fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix"<"#tInfo">f>t'
}`
How can I clarify, that I want to add header in a new way?

DataTables live - http://live.datatables.net/petupeto/1/edit?html,js,output
Fiddle - http://fiddle.jshell.net/2syoa2gv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some researches and found that dataTables.jqueryui just extends default settings of datatables.

```
$.extend( true, DataTable.defaults, {
    dom:
        '<"'+toolbar_prefix+'tl ui-corner-tr"lfr>'+
        't'+
        '<"'+toolbar_prefix+'bl ui-corner-br"ip>',
    renderer: 'jqueryui'
} );
```

so there is no any ability to make custom header with jquery-ui integration in new way